Interchange expectation and sup
Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable and $f$ be a function defined from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb R$.
I am looking for sufficient conditions under which: $$\sup_{\beta\in B} \mathbb{E} f(X, \beta) = \mathbb{E} \sup_{\beta\in B} f(X, \beta),$$
where $B$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The expectation is with respect to $X$ and the $\sup$ is with respect to a scalar $\beta$.
It is easy to show that $\sup_{\beta\in B} \mathbb{E} f(X, \beta) \leq \mathbb{E} \sup_{\beta\in B} f(X, \beta)$ but the second inequality is not easy.
I found theorems dealing with the case where $\beta$ is a function of $X$ and it is too complicated to understand. I guess that, for the case where $\beta$ is a scalar, there should be a simple theorem somewhere.
EDIT: I know that there is a function $g$ such that $\lvert f(X, \beta)\rvert \leq \lvert g(X, \beta) \rvert$, where $\mathbb E \lvert g(X, \beta) \rvert < \infty$. I do not know if something like the dominated convergence theorem that allows to interchange limit and expectation exists for expectation and $\sup$.

It works when the expectations exist (such as when the function is  bounded and measurable) and there is a $\beta^\in B$ for which $f(x,\beta)\leq f(x,\beta^)$ for all $x,\beta$. Clearly it does not hold in general.

Thanks @Michael Yes I can assume that the expectations. Do you have like a reference I can cite?

For expectations to exist, lets assume $f$ is bounded and measurable. We already know
$$ \sup_{\beta \in B} E[f(X,\beta)]\leq E\left[\sup_{\beta \in B} f(X,\beta)\right] \quad (Eq. 1)$$

Claim: If $f$ has the property that there is a $\beta^*\in B$ such that
$$ f(x,\beta)\leq f(x,\beta^*) \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \beta \in B$$
then for any random variable $X$ we have
$$  \sup_{\beta \in B} E[f(X,\beta)]= E\left[\sup_{\beta \in B} f(X,\beta)\right] $$
Proof: We know
$$\sup_{\beta \in B} f(x,\beta) = f(x,\beta^*) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
and so for any random variable $X$ we have
$$\sup_{\beta \in B} f(X,\beta) = f(X,\beta^*) \quad (Eq. 2)$$
Then for any random variable $X$:
\begin{align}
\sup_{\beta \in B} E[f(X,\beta)] &\overset{(a)}{\geq} E[f(X,\beta^*)]\\
&\overset{(b)}{=}E\left[\sup_{\beta \in B} f(X,\beta)\right]\\
&\overset{(c)}{\geq} \sup_{\beta \in B} E[f(X,\beta)]
\end{align}
where (a) holds because $\beta^* \in B$; (b) holds by Eq. (2); (c) holds by Eq. (1).
$\Box$

Thank you for your answer.
I think the condition that there is such $\beta^*$ that does not depend on $x$ is a strong condition for me. For the expectation to exist, I only know that $f(X, \beta)$ is bounded by some $g(X, \beta)$ which is uniformly integrable.
